# How do we get a -1 in a 1-bit ALU?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, adder, alu, function

In the 1-bit ALU and the table that is shown below, as you can see, the output is -1 when F0 = 1, F1 = 1, ENA = 0, ENB = 0, INVA = 1, INC = 0. The table is taken from a book (Structured Computer Organization
Book by Andrew S. Tanenbaum, Chapter 4, Section 4.1, Figure 4.2).  The diagram is from Figure 3-18 in the book.  Sadly, this was not explained anywhere.

[image]

[image]

I am well aware of the fact that when F0 and F1 are both 1, addition is going to take place between A and B. As ENA and ENB are both zeroes, we are basically zeroing the AND gates with A. For what I know, INVA complements the value of A if it is set, that is, I am going to get a 0 if A is 1 and 1 if A is 0.

How are we landing to a -1 output from these?

Answer (score 1):

The top diagram represents a 1-bit slice of an N-bit ALU, as shown in Figure 3-18.  Figure 3-19 shows an example diagram of an 8-bit ALU, where 8 of the 1-bit blocks are connected together.

Figure 4-2 assumes that you have more than 1 bit, for example an 8-bit ALU.  The bottom row in the table is -1, which we can infer from the text, is a 2's-complement value.  -1 means that the output of each of the 8 ALU bits is 1.  In Figure 3-19, this means that O0=1, O1=1, ..., O7=1.

Fig. 3-19 also shows that `Carry in` of the 1st ALU bit is connected to `INC`, which from the last row in the table is 0.  The combination of the other inputs forces `Carry out` of each ALU bit to follow `Carry in`.  This means the `Carry out` of all 8 ALU bits is 0.

Also, the combination of the inputs forces the output of each ALU bit to follow `Sum`, which is forced to 1.  When the F inputs are 1, this sets the 3 outputs of the "Logical unit" to 0, which means `Output` follows `Sum` and `Sum` is controlled by the XOR gate.  Since `Carry in` is always 0, the output of the other XOR gate in "Full adder" is 1.  Therefore, `Sum` is 1.